# Не могу поставить php7.2 на ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, php7.2

Прописал

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Пишу

```
sudo apt install -y php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common
```

Получаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И попал в тупик. Помогите пожалуйста :с
Работаю с ubuntu 16.04 lts и прежде чем написать сюда попробовал выполнить манипуляции с нескольких сайтов. Вот один из них: https://andreyex.ru/ubuntu/kak-ustanovit-php-7-2-na-ubuntu-16-04/
**Дополнение:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю..., но я легко разворачивал сервер на debian 10, а тут прям жесть какая-то :с      
Не знаю важно ли это, но ставлю php под apache2

Comment: Выглядит так, будто вы забыли сделать add-apt-repository

Comment: https://andreyex.ru/ubuntu/kak-ustanovit-php-7-2-na-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: @andreymal, вроде да, не делал. Нужно просто написать эту команду? Или ещё что-то? На дебиан просто не испытывал таких проблем)

Comment: А не, писал add-apt-repository

Comment: Сейчас попробую ещё раз

Comment: Проделал эти действия ещё раз. Результат в дополнении вопроса :с

Comment: @ArchDemon, по этой инструкции я и действовал, всё равно беда(

Comment: Советую обновиться до более новой версии ubuntu. Любой лёгкий способ установки уже не прокатит.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению мне так и не удалось решить эту проблему на ubuntu 16.04 lts.
Могу сказать, что прежде чем забить на это я:

1. Перекопал кучу форумов и статей
2. Попытался найти старые репозитории по которым я могу скачать пхп7.2 (не нашёл. И сразу упомяну то, что все статьи по установке пхп7.2 с репозитория ondrej:ppa(или как-то так) устарели и этот способ больше не работает(по крайней мере на этой убунту))
3. Откопал статью в которой было предложено скачать пхп7.2 с исходников php (можно найти тут https://github.com/php/php-src в разделе tags), но и с этим вариантом я обломался, ибо словил кучу ошибок :(. Не утверждаю, что этот пункт точно не работает...возможно я не смог найти для себя достаточно инфы. В общем-то можете попробовать)
4. Пришёл к выводу, что лучше оставить прошлое в прошлом и сделал переход на debian10. Проблем не встретил, ибо ОС на мой взгляд похожи и имеют один пакетный менеджер. Тьфу-тьфу-тьфу, работает без проблем)
   P.S. Если вы как и я придёте к 4-му пункту, то очень советую данный видеоролик по установке https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cNkbotSREU&list=LL&index=17 . Всё как в статьях, но показывается по факту что и как делать